# $not not performing $and operation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I just started exploring mongoDB. During that time I managed to create a simple collection with the following data,

```
db.test.insert({name : "joe", age : 20});
db.test.insert({name: "james", age : 25});
```

Now I have queried it by using,

```
db.test.find({name : {$not : {$eq : "joe", $eq: "james"}}})
```

It yielded me the following result,

```
{name : "joe", age : 20}
```

I am confused here, Is it not an and operation like below,

```
SELECT * FROM test where not name = "joe" and not name = "james"
```

**Doubt1:** If yes then how the above mentioned mongo query can be interpreted as a normal mysql query? [Note : I am coming from a mysql background.] Please explain.

**Doubt2:** Also explain about the following mongo query,

```
db.test.find({name : "joe", age : 20});
```

Is the above query equals to `select * from test where name='joe' and age=20` ? If not then how it would be interpreted as a normal mysql query?

Answer (score 4):

When you are creating an object with `{$eq : "joe", $eq: "james"}` you are using the same object key twice. So `james` will overwrite `joe` because both use the same object key `$eq`.

To do your query, you can try something like `NOT (name = "joe" OR name = "james")`. So you add the `OR` to your mongo query:

```
db.test.find({name : {$nor: [{$eq: "joe"}, $eq: "james"]}})
```

[Reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nor/)

Comment: It has cleared my doubts. I didn't think about having same keys twice. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Your query gave me this error, `db.test.find({name : {$not : {$or: [{$eq: "joe"}, {$eq: "james"}]}}})                                                                   
Error: error: {"$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown operator: $or","code" : 17287}`

Comment: Can't I use `$or`/`$and` inside of `$not` ?

Comment: I've updated my answer. It should be clearer and correct now, using MongoDB's `$nor`

Comment: `Error: error: {"$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown operator: $nor","code" : 17287}` Your new update Gave me the above error. As per the document, $or/$and/$nor can be used immediate to themselves, not with others.

Answer (score 1):

I guess [Christoph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6649773/christoph) cleared your doubts.

For SQL to Mongo Query reference visit [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/sql-comparison/) link

Comment: Very useful link!! Thank you.